# mysql - Mix two statements

Tags: mysql, select

Please help to mix this two statement to one statement:

1. `SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE`pro_status`='1' or`pro_status`='2'`
2. `SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE`loca_city`= 'tw' or loca_city` = 'usa'`

*I need statement 1 's result to do statement 2.*

```
//Property Status -0=suspended;1=valid(NORMALl);2=valid(GOOD);3=no/wrong number.
Data Base

ref pro_type    loca_city   pro_statusRemarks: 
00001   Industrial  HK      0
00002   Industrial  TW      2
00003   Commercial  HK      2
00004   Retail      TW      0
00005   Others      HK      2
00006   Retail      HK      2
00007   Others      HK      2
00008   Retail      USA     2
00009   Retail      HK      1
00010   Retail      HK      1
00011   Retail      TW      2
00012   Retail      HK      2
00013   Retail      HK      2
00014   Retail      HK      2
00015   Retail      HK      2
00016   Commercial  HK      1
00017   Retail      HK      1
00018   Others      HK      1
```

need result:

```
ref pro_type    loca_city   pro_statusRemarks: 
00002   Industrial  TW      2
00008   Retail      USA     2
00011   Retail      TW      2
```

Comment: if use 
SELECT 
* 
FROM inventory 
WHERE `pro_status`='1' or `pro_status`='2' OR `loca_city` = 'hk' or `loca_city` = 'tw' or `loca_city` = 'usa'

**result will include `pro_status`='0' record.

Answer (score 3):

You need to combine the respective filters with [`AND`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/logical-operators.html#operator_and) (beware to include parentheses around them in order to enforce the desired precedence):

```
SELECT *
FROM   inventory
WHERE  (`pro_status`='1' or `pro_status`='2')
   AND (`loca_city` = 'hk' or `loca_city` = 'tw' or loca_city` = 'usa')
```

The conditions can be simplified using MySQL's [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   inventory
WHERE  pro_status IN (1,2)
   AND loca_city IN ('hk','tw','usa')
```

Answer (score 0):

If both the queries are on the same table and all the conditions are `OR` you can directly do :

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM inventory 
WHERE `pro_status`='1' or `pro_status`='2' 
OR `loca_city` = 'hk' or `loca_city` = 'tw' or `loca_city` = '
```

Comment: if use 
SELECT 
* 
FROM inventory 
WHERE `pro_status`='1' or `pro_status`='2' OR `loca_city` = 'hk' or `loca_city` = 'tw' or `loca_city` = 'usa'

result will include `pro_status`='3' record.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM inventory 
WHERE `pro_status`='1' 
   OR `pro_status`='2' 
   OR `loca_city` = 'hk' 
   OR `loca_city` = 'tw' 
   OR loca_city` = 'usa'
```

Comment: **result will include pro_status='0' record